# Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: database-administration

How can I resolve this error:

> Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Banking.mdf'.

Comment: this looks offtopic as it is answered on the DBA stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have the appropriate account permissions on the account in order to access the folder the mdf file is located in.

More detail can be found in the following link.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22250/sql-server-create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I called 'update-database' the first time I tried to run Entity Framework Core / EF Core.

I solved it!

The full error message was:
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\peterObjectData.mdf'.

Creating files in C:\Users\ directory requires admin rights.

To fix this, one can add a file location and name for the mdf file in the connection string:
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Database = ObjectData; Trusted_Connection = True; AttachDbFileName=D:\Databases\ObjectDB.mdf");

Here, "D:\Databases\ObjectDB.mdf" is the location and filename of the .mdf file created. This fixed my issue.

If you want to read more on ConnectionStrings and AttachDbFileName, here's the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Answer (score 0):

That must be your C drive denied the SQL server to create file. You can either change the direction to other drive(D:;E:) or if you dont want to, then you have to change the security properties for your C:\ drive. Right click C:, choose properties, security, change authenticate user and user to full control then you good